# SQL Many-to-many relation design

Tags: sql

Can i achieve a many-to-many relationship without using a junction table with the below 2 tables?

**Airports table:**

```
create table if not exists airports
(
    id int not null auto_increment, 
    airport_name varchar(20) not null, 
    aeroplane_id int, 
    foreign key (aeroplane_id) references aeroplanes(id),
    primary key (id)
);
```

**Aeroplanes Table**

```
create table if not exists aeroplanes
(
    id int not null auto_increment, 
    aeroplane_name varchar(20) not null,
    airport_id int,
    foreign key (airport_id) references airports(id),
    primary key (id)
);
```

If not then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes you can, but you shouldn't!

Without an extra relation, you would need a copy of the whole entry.

So in your case: every airport has zero (or one) or more planes. And every plane was at one or more airports. When saving this in one relation your data will look like this:

```
airportId1, "airportName1", planeId1
airPortId1, "airportName1", planeId2
airPortId2, "airportName2", planeId1
...
```

(and similar for the `areoplanes` table)

This would cause some problems in your DB:

1. The Primary Key for airport isn't unique anymore
2. You will need to maintain a lot of copies of your data and make sure that you update all of them!

So the better table design in your scenario would be

```
airport(airport_id,name)
aeroplanes(plane_id, name)
airports_and_planes(airport_id, plane_id)
```

Where in `airports_and_planes`:

- both fields are foreign keys to their repsective tables
- both fields form the primary key **together**!

Comment: That's seems valid , i couldn't understand this point "You will need to maintain a lot of copies of your data and make sure that you update all of them" though

Comment: I mean that you have a copy of each row (e.g., "airportId1, airportName1"). This will increase the size of your table significantly and may be a problem if you have a huge amount of entries. If there is an `UPDATE` operation, you need to update all of these copies! Otherwise you have inconsistent data.